# DateAdd no se actualiza en iteración

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Buen día a todos, tengo un problema estoy trabajando en un planeador de fabricación para proyectos en donde tengo un TextBox1 para la fecha de inicio y un TextBox4 para el numero de carretes=Ci, el usuario debe especificar cuantos Ci (Carretes) serán y a partir de ahí comience la planeación del programa de fabricación.

Toda esta información es vaciada en un DataGridView en donde tengo columnas donde está el "Departamento" "Sección" " Operación" "Fecha final" "Fecha inicial"

El problema es cuando mi código comienza con el Carrete No 2, me asigna las mismas fechas calculadas para el Carrete No 1, algo así.

```
Manufacturing   Channel Cut plate C1            04/07/2019  04/07/2019
Manufacturing   Channel Rolled plate C1         04/07/2019  04/07/2019
Manufacturing   Channel Longituidal welding C1  08/07/2019  09/07/2019
Manufacturing   Channel Re rolled C1            10/07/2019  11/07/2019
Manufacturing   Channel Cut plate C2            04/07/2019  04/07/2019
Manufacturing   Channel Rolled plate C2         04/07/2019  04/07/2019
Manufacturing   Channel Longituidal welding C2  08/07/2019  09/07/2019
Manufacturing   Chanel  rolled C2               10/07/2019  11/07/2019
```

Necesito que en el Carrete del C2 comience desde la fecha de la última actividad del Carrete 1 y quede, algo así.

```
Manufacturing   Channel Cut plate C1            04/07/2019  04/07/2019
Manufacturing   Channel Rolled plate C1         05/07/2019  05/07/2019
Manufacturing   Channel Longituidal welding C1  06/07/2019  07/07/2019
Manufacturing   Channel Re rolled C1            10/07/2019  11/07/2019
Manufacturing   Channel Cut plate C2            11/07/2019  12/07/2019
Manufacturing   Channel Rolled plate C2         13/07/2019  14/07/2019
Manufacturing   Channel Longituidal welding C2  15/07/2019  16/07/2019
Manufacturing   Chanel  rolled C2               17/07/2019  18/07/2019
```

El código con el que estuve trabajando es el siguiente.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
       Dim fecha1 As Date = CType(TextBox1.Text, Date)
        Dim numRows As Integer
        If Integer.TryParse(TextBox4.Text, numRows) Then
        If (numRows >= 1) Then
        For i As Integer = 1 To numRows
        Table.Rows.Add("Manufacturing", "Channel", "Cut plate C" & i, DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 1, fecha1), DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 2, fecha1))
        Table.Rows.Add("Manufacturing", "Channel", "Rolled plate C" & i, DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 3, fecha1), DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 4, fecha1))
        Table.Rows.Add("Manufacturing", "Channel", "Longituidal welding C" & i, DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 5, fecha1), DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 6, fecha1))
        Table.Rows.Add("Manufacturing", "Channel", "Re rolled C" & i, DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 7, fecha1), DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 8, fecha1))
        Next
        Else
        MessageBox.Show("Value: " & TextBox4.Text, "El número de filas debe ser mayor o igual a 1")
        End If
        Else
        MessageBox.Show("Value: " & TextBox4.Text, "Número invalido")
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Ademas de agregar lo que queres, agrega un ejemplo de como te sale...

Comment: Ahh.. ya entendi.. magicamente.. y quien ejecuta todo este codigo? porque el problema es que cada vez que se ejecuta este codigo, reinicia la fecha (que parece que no es lo que queres)

Comment: Un usuario es el que definirá los números de Ci, así es mi problema es el reinicio en las fechas, deseo obtener el seguimiento de los días posteriores.

Comment: Explica un poco mejor de donde viene ese codigo y la forma de interaccion con el usuario. Vos creas una fecha nueva ahi cada vez que ejecutas esa funcion. Eso debe ir en otro lado o tomar el valor de algun lado. Asi como esta, es dificil decirte donde porque falta mucha info para saber como arreglarlo. Por fa mira los enlaces que te pase, y trata de contarnos un poco mas del escenario

Comment: @gbianchi he editado mi post después de leer el enlace que me pasaste, intenté ser un poco más claro ampliando el escenario, espero me puedan apoyar, gracias por tu retroalimentación, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Aca hay un problema de logica y esta en esta linea:

```
Dim fecha1 As Date = CType(TextBox1.Text, Date)
```

Cada vez que el usuario hace click en el boton, esa fecha1 vuelve a venir del textbox, y se vuelve a iniciar.

Entonces, posibles soluciones son:

- Guardar esa fecha al terminar en el textbox:

Algo asi como:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ....
    End If
    TextBox1.Text = fecha1 'cuidado aca con el formato
End Sub
```

- Solo leer la fecha una vez, en algun otro lado
- Usar un flag para saber cuando leer la fecha, y definir la fecha fuera del boton

Algo asi:

```
dim fechaleida as boolean = false
Dim fecha1 As Date
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If (not fechaleida)
        fecha1 = CType(TextBox1.Text, Date)
        fechaleida = true
    End if
    ....
    End If
End Sub
```